# Using structs in parametric types, not only primitive types

Tags: parameters, julia, type-inference, arbitrary-precision

The problem arose while I was working with [Mods.jl](https://github.com/scheinerman/Mods.jl). This package does not support arbitrary-precision arithmetic because only primitive types can be passed as parameters, i.e. `Mod{17}` works fine, but `Mod{big"17"}` not.

Due to this I decided to implement something like `BigMod` with two `BigInt` fields

```
struct BigMod <: AbstractMod
    value::BigInt
    modulus::BigInt
end
```

Then I had to solve system of linear comparisons, and whilst it worked pretty good for `Mod{N}` (`A \ b` with some additional magic) it didn't worked for `BigMod` at all.

The reason was that `LinearAlgebra` package [uses](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/src/factorization.jl#L104) `oneunit` function to inference types, but there's no way to define `oneunit(::Type{BigMod})`, because we don't know modulus in this case (but we do know it for `Mod{N}`). However this function could be defined for variable of the type `BigMod`, i.e. `oneunit(x::BigMod)`.

This problem can be solved using `Base.return_types` inside of `LinearAlgebra` for type inference, however it seems to be type unstable as well as it returns a collection of possible return types.

I can see only three ways to solve this:

1. One day one could use any (at least immutable) types in parameters. In this case no additional code is required, original should be generic enough for everything to work well.
2. One day type inference would be improved enough so that no kludges like `typeof(oneunit(eltype(B)) / oneunit(eltype(F)))` are needed, one can just say `return_type(/, eltype.((B,F)))` which is much more generic.
3. Fight through the pain and rewrite all necessary things from `LinearAlgebra` specially for `BigMod`

Are there any other ways to reach the goal and what way is the best?

Comment: If you do end up rewriting stuff, I'd suggest keeping values in fields instead of type parameters, like the `BigMod` you posted. The `Mod{N}` approach in Mods.jl worked fine because `Int64` was allowed and more than big enough for most cases. Waiting for the core language to allow more things as type parameters isn't practical. At some point it was expanded from only `Int` and `Bool` to isbits types, so there must've been some intractable reason they didn't expand it further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parametric types can only contain `isbits` or `Symbol`s. Hence, you could use a very easy to implement, yet extremely dirty and inefficient workaround.

```
struct MyBigMod{S} <: AbstractMod
    value::BigInt
end

Base.oneunit(::MyBigMod{S}) where S = parse(BigInt, string(S))
```

And now you could use it as:

```
julia> oneunit(MyBigMod{Symbol("55555555555555555555555")}(big"222222"))
55555555555555555555555
```

Perhaps your big ints are not that big after all and you could consider `using BitIntegers`? Than you could do something like:

```
julia> MyBigMod{int1024"55555555555555555555555"}
MyBigMod{55555555555555555555555}
```

Comment: Didn't know about `BitIntegers` your answer made all clear. Thanks!!!